# Python Regex Question

Tags: python, regex

I have an end tag  followed by a carriage return line feed (x0Dx0A) followd by one or more tabs (x09) followed by a new start tag .

Something like this:

```
</tag1>x0Dx0Ax09x09x09<tag2> or </tag1>x0Dx0Ax09x09x09x09x09<tag2>
```

What Python regex should I use to replace it with something like this:

```
</tag1><tag3>content</tag3><tag2>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Parsing XML yourself? Not a good idea. IT seams that you will have additional problems porting your code to Python 3. How about trying to use an existing xml parsing solutions instead?

Answer (score 1):

Here is code for something like what you say that you need:

```
>>> import re
>>> sample = '</tag1>\r\n\t\t\t\t<tag2>'
>>> sample
'</tag1>\r\n\t\t\t\t<tag2>'
>>> pattern = '(</tag1>)\r\n\t+(<tag2>)'
>>> replacement = r'\1<tag3>content</tag3>\2'
>>> re.sub(pattern, replacement, sample)
'</tag1><tag3>content</tag3><tag2>'
>>>
```

Note that `\r\n\t+` may be a bit too specific, especially if production of your input is not under your control. It may be better to adopt the much more general `\s*` (zero or more whitespace characters).

Using regexes to parse XML and HTML is not a good idea in general ... while it's hard to see a failure mode here (apart from elementary errors in getting the pattern correct), you might like to tell us what the underlying problem is, in case some other solution is better.